# FluidTYPO3 fluidpages – custom page controller not found

Tags: controller, typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

I am building a website with TYPO3 9.5 and the [Fluid Powered TYPO3](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3) extensions, and I will need to access GET and POST variables in my fluidpages templates.

I tried to create a custom PageController to do this ; here is the class I added in `…myext/Classes/Controller/PageController.php` :

```php
<?php

namespace MyVendor\MyExt\Controller;

use FluidTYPO3\Fluidpages\Controller;

class PageController extends Controller\PageController
{
    protected function initializeViewVariables() {
        parent::initializeViewVariables();
        $GETarray = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GET();
        $this->view->assign('GET', $GETarray);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this method never seems to be executed, as if my class weren’t found. When I display `GET` in the template file with `<f:debug>{GET}</f:debug>`, the result is always `NULL` whatever parameters I added in the URL. I tried assigning another, fixed variable with `view->assign`, and it’s `NULL` too. The code above does not have syntax errors, I’m using PHPStorm, which finds the parent class and shows that my `initializeViewVariables` method overrides the one in `AbstractFluxController`.

What I have tried :

- I followed what the documentation explains [here](https://fluidtypo3.org/documentation/templating-manual/templating/provider-extension/registration-in-php.html) : registered my extension with a key of the form `MyVendorName.Myextensionkey`. I created a `ClassAliasMap.php` file, even though I don’t think it would be needed for TYPO3 9.5 ?
- in the `composer.json` file in my extension, I added :

  ```php
  "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
          "MyVendor\\MyExt\\": "Classes"
      }
  }
  ```

  and in the `composer.json` for my entire TYPO3 project, I put :

  ```php
  "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
          "MyVendor\\MyExt\\": "public/typo3conf/ext/myext/Classes"
      }
  }
  ```

  and I have verified that this path appears in `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` after I used the `composer dump-autoload` command. I also have the autoload information in the `ext_emconf.php` file
- cleared all the caches in TYPO3
- I don’t have any error message either in TYPO3 or in the Apache logs when I view the page

And it still doesn’t work. Autoloading works if I call a method of a class in the Typoscript of a page with `userFunc`, however. Do you see what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for now (hopefully I will be able to add more details later) : in order to have the above Controller be called for a certain page, we need to add an action, even an empty one, with the same name as the template. For example if our page template is `Foo.html`, it will work if we add an action method :

```
public function fooAction() {

}
```

to the `PageController` class